# Hebrew causes tikz-uml to not work

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, hebrew, compilation-error, tikz-uml

The following code works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{umlpackage}[x=0, y=0, type=class] {hi}
  \end{umlpackage}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, when I add Hebrew as one of the languages `babel` uses so:

```
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
```

The code does not compile! With any other language it tried beside Russian it worked. Any idea why this might happen?

The errors:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.12 ...gin{umlpackage}[x=0, y=0, type=class] {hi}

? 
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.12 ...gin{umlpackage}[x=0, y=0, type=class] {hi}

? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.12 ...gin{umlpackage}[x=0, y=0, type=class] {hi}

? 
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no > in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
! Undefined control sequence.
\\umlpackage ...parent {\tikzumlPackage@parentold 
                                                  @@\tikzumlPackage@nameold ...
l.12 ...gin{umlpackage}[x=0, y=0, type=class] {hi}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\\umlpackage ...rentold @@\tikzumlPackage@nameold 
                                                  }\else \def \tikzumlPackag...
l.12 ...gin{umlpackage}[x=0, y=0, type=class] {hi}

? 
Missing character: There is no h in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no h in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.13   \end{umlpackage}

? 
Missing character: There is no 0 in font nullfont!
! Extra \endcsname.
\pgfutil@ifundefined ...\ifx \csname #1\endcsname 
                                                  \relax \expandafter \pgfut...
l.13   \end{umlpackage}

? 

! Package pgf Error: Sorry, the requested layer 'package\@@number{0}' could not
 be found. Maybe you misspelled it?.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13   \end{umlpackage}

? 
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10.95> on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 13.

! LaTeX Error: \begin{scope} on input line 12 ended by \end{pgfonlayer}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13   \end{umlpackage}

? 

! LaTeX Error: \begin{umlpackage} on input line 12 ended by \end{scope}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13   \end{umlpackage}

? 

! LaTeX Error: \begin{tikzpicture} on input line 11 ended by \end{umlpackage}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13   \end{umlpackage}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfsys@call@end ->\pgfsys@end@save 
                                    \pgfsys@endscope 
l.14 \end{tikzpicture}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\endpgfscope ...pgflinewidth =\pgfscope@linewidth 
                                                  \global \let \pgf@strokeco...
l.14 \end{tikzpicture}

? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
l.14 \end{tikzpicture}

? 
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
l.14 \end{tikzpicture}

? 
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.14 \end{tikzpicture}

? 
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endpgfpicture ...globally \endgroup \hss \egroup 
                                                  \pgf@restore@layerlist@fro...
l.14 \end{tikzpicture}

? 
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.14 \end{tikzpicture}

? 
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endpgfpicture ...dpicture \endgroup \hss \egroup 
                                                  \pgfsys@typesetpicturebox ...
l.14 \end{tikzpicture}

? 

! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{tikzpicture}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14 \end{tikzpicture}

? 
! Extra \endgroup.
<recently read> \endgroup 

l.14 \end{tikzpicture}

? 
! Infinite glue shrinkage found in a paragraph.
l.15
```

Please note that I can compile Hebrew on my machine without `tikz-uml`.

Comment: Welcome! Try adding \usetikzlibrary{babel}

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat this did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Which error do you get exactly?

Comment: @Marijn I've added the errors to my post.